# Cannot find html tag I am looking for from new york times when webscraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My goal is to use python to web scrape nytimes.com and find today's date.
I did some research and here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import requests

link="https://www.nytimes.com/"
response=requests.get(link)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
time = soup.findAll("span",{"data-testid": "todays-date"})
print(time)
```

This is a picture of the html from nytimes website:
[screenshot from nytimes html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFeHv.jpg)

And this is what my terminal found after running the code - the list is empty, it could not find anything:
[An empty list shown on my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT1jS.png)

Comment: You want to get the date and nothing else ? Are you scraping this just for the date ?

Comment: @Ram Yes it is an assignment I have to complete..

Answer (score 1):

I think the element might be rendered via JS, so you don't find it when downloading the html via requests.

```
masthead = soup.find('section', {'id':'masthead-bar-one'})
```

What you get is

```
<section class="hasLinks css-1oajkic e1csuq9d3" id="masthead-bar-one"><div><div class="css-1jxco98 e1csuq9d0"></div><div class="css-bfvq22 e1csuq9d2"><a class="css-hnzl8o" href="https://www.nytimes.com/section/todayspaper">Today’s Paper</a></div></div><div class="css-103zufb" id="masthead-bar-one-widgets"><div class="css-i1s3vq e1csuq9d1"></div><div class="css-77hcv e1ll57lj2"></div></div><div class="css-9e9ivx"><a class="css-1k0lris" data-testid="login-link" href="https://myaccount.nytimes.com/auth/login?response_type=cookie&amp;client_id=vi"></a></div></section>
```

No sign at all of the element you are looking for. I would suggest you to look into the `selenium` library in order to do this - it mocks a browser and therefore you can scrape also data generated by JS.